# How can replace a string within single quotes with a value stored in a variable?

Tags: sed

I want to use a sed command in as script to change the Ansible version in a file from `'2.7'` to `2.9` and keep the single quotes, `'`.

This is what I use, but it seems like the result does not have the single quotes:

```
sed -i 's/^ansible::version:.*/ansible::version:'$vers'/' /path_to_file
```

output:

```
ansible::version: 2.9
```

This is the content of the file:

```
ansible::version: '2.7'
```

Comment: @jared_mamrot No need to escape single quotes within a double quoted string, also not for BSD sed.

Comment: @jared_mamrot ...but the `.` *should* be escaped, or it matches anything ;)

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminW. - I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

BSD sed: `sed "s/'2\.7'/'2\.9'/g" file` & GNU sed: `sed "s/'2\.7'/'2\.9'/g" file`